# How to add ProgressDialog in VideoView?

Tags: android, progressdialog, android-videoview

Is there anyway I can add a ProgressDialog in VideoView in Android while the video is not showing up yet. Because all I see is black screen until the video plays. I have struggling for almost a week trying to find the solution, please help me I would really appreciate it a lot. Thanks in advance!

Here is the code I am using:

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
    // Set video link (mp4 format )
    Uri video = Uri.parse("http://www.yourvideos.mp4");
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.setVideoURI(video);
    videoView.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't test this but you might add the dialog, and populate it with the percentage fetched by http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MediaController.MediaPlayerControl.html#getBufferPercentage()

use something like a timer to update it every few ms

Comment: getBufferPercentage returns 0 for me until the video starts to play, so this does not work.

Answer (score 2):

best way is to use async task...  preExecute method use showing dialog... doInBackground for setting the videoUri then in onPostExecute cancel the dialog... but if u had need to stop the Loading dialog as video starts playing, implement onPreparedListener and Register for
 the video view
 if you dont to want use async task then show the dialog before u set the path to videoview. then cancel it on "OnPrepared" listeners "onPrepared()" method. remember u should register with videoview...